# Table Editing in Javascript; Time to short

Tags: javascript, timeout, jeditable

I was trying to use JEditable so that my DataTable could be edited but the issue is that the user gets roughly 1 second to edit the column, no one I know can make changes that quick making the idea great but useless. So my question is that is there a way to make the editable textarea stay around longer so that a person can actually edit it? Or is there another Javascript method like JEditable that I can use?

Comment: sounds like you have some other issue...

Comment: As far as I can see, JEditable does not have a 1 second limit. That would be insane. There must be something else going on in your code. Perhaps if you showed us your code we could figure it out. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: `<textarea>` is editable, and doesn't disappear unless something tells it too - impossible question to answer : )

Comment: When I go to https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html I get the same result... a second to edit the table which is why I thought it is not my code particularly. I just tried this in Firefox and it works fine, I was using Chrome before. Anyone else get this same behavior in Chrome?